# iOS touches entered from outside UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, multi-touch, touches

I'm trying to build a virtual piano keyboard for iOS. One of the biggest problem's I'm having is how to handle touches that start outside a UIView and then enter it. Since the touchesBegan is being called on another view, I can't figure out how to get the touch recognized by the target view when the touch moves inside it.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: have you tried implementing the touchMoved method???

Comment: Yes, but the touchMoved method only gets called if the touch starts INSIDE the UIView. I want to track touches that start outside the view and move inwards.